# why Builder builder instead of alertdialoge.Builder?

Tags: android

i am new to android and got struck tn the following statement:

```
Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

but, as we know that Builder is the static inner class of `AlertDialoge` class, the statement should be:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new Alertdialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: You can google it , it is related to Java syntax

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to keep a AlertDialog.Builder reference in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Because of your `import` statement.

I guess you have an

```
import AlertDialog.Builder
```

in your header. You can remove this `import` but then you have to declare your variable as `AlertDialog.Builder`.